# Apple mach-o linker error with Amazon AWS and Paypal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, paypal

So I am using Amazon AWS, specifically their content delivery with S3, and I am trying to integrate paypal as well. However, I'm having trouble getting paypal to work in conjunction with aws. Right now, I have "-lc++ -ObjC" added to the "Other linker flags" in my project settings. When I try to run, I get this huge list of errors, all having to do with AWS frameworks I don't even use.

Here is the list of errors. 
[ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFov2.png)

Comment: Have you tried removing the -ObjC from your other linker flags settings?

Answer (score 1):

Right now you can't use the -ObjC linker setting when using the Mobile Hub helper code (we are working on a fix).  What you can do instead is use the -force_load linker option to load the libraries that you put the -ObjC flag in for (PayPal).

Comment: An update on this issue, it was fixed in the 2.6.1 version of the SDK released at the end of August.